# Not able to send error messages in sentry

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, sentry, logstash-logback-encoder

I am using below dependency in my spring boot project for sending error messages in sentry server.

```
compile 'io.sentry:sentry-logback:1.7.5'
compile('net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:4.7')
compile group: 'ch.qos.logback.contrib', name: 'logback-json-classic', version: '0.1.5'
compile group: 'ch.qos.logback.contrib', name: 'logback-jackson', version: '0.1.5'
```

I have configured SENTRY_DSN value in manifest.yml file. And log level in below logback.xml

```
<configuration>
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender" >
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder"/>
</appender>
<appender name="SENTRY" class="io.sentry.logback.SentryAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>ERROR</level>
    </filter>
</appender>

<root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="SENTRY"/>
</root>
```

When I am trying to sent some messages in sentry, I am getting below error:

```
io.sentry.connection.ConnectionException: An exception occurred while submitting the event to the Sentry server.
at io.sentry.connection.HttpConnection.doSend(HttpConnection.java:216)
at io.sentry.connection.AbstractConnection.send(AbstractConnection.java:76)
at io.sentry.connection.AsyncConnection$EventSubmitter.run(AsyncConnection.java:185)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:933)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:735)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1587)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
at io.sentry.connection.HttpConnection.doSend(HttpConnection.java:172)
... 5 common frames omitted
```

Could you please let me know how to resolve this exception and sent logs to sentry server.

Note: I have configured SENTRY logs notification in Slack channel.

Comment: 'io.sentry:sentry-logback:1.7.5' is pretty old. Do you mind trying 1.7.30? Releases are here: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/releases Do you get this error on your dev machine or on the server? Does the process have access to the Internet? Perhaps you need a proxy?